# Jquery - Stop clicking before the document is ready

Tags: jquery

I want to stop click on any links until the page is loaded.

Can you help me how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var donclick=true;
$(document).ready(function () {
  dontclick=false;
}
$(document).click(function(e){
  if(dontclick && e.target.tagName=='INPUT') e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just need to change the 'INPUT' to 'A' :)